# how to left join a table with a query?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have three tables

usertbl

```
id | fname | lname  
---|-------|------  
1  |  ali  | rahimi  
2  | reza  | miri
```

citytbl

```
id | cityname  
---|-------  
1  |  ahvaz  
2  | shiraz  
3  | mashad
```

TBl3

```
Cityid| userid| Value  
------|-------|------  
1     |  1    | 10  
2     |  1    | 30
```

Result that i want is:

```
Cityid| userid| Value  
------|-------|------  
1     |  1    | 10  
2     |  1    | 30   
3     |  1    | 0  
1     |  2    | 0  
2     |  2    | 0  
3     |  2    | 0
```

I try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM usertbl, citytbl  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 ON
    (tbl3.cityid=citytbl.id AND
     tb.l3.userid=usertbl.id)
```

but it did not worked.

Comment: What is your join condition between the tables "usertbl" and "citytbl"?

Comment: @EstebanP. There is no condition...i want to have every user with every city

Comment: Don't mix comma separated, implicit joins with explicit JOIN's. Too confusing for most of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be: 
If you really want to have every user with every city, you can use a `CROSS JOIN`.
As you finally want to add the value use the `LEFT JOIN.`  
To get a 0 instead of NULL (if there is no match in the Tbl3), use the `COALESCE`.

```
         SELECT c.id as Cityid
               ,u.id as userID
               ,COALESCE(t3.value,0) as value
           FROM usertbl u
     CROSS JOIN citytbl c
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBl3 t3
             ON t3.userid = u.id
            AND t3.cityid = c.id
```

I've also added a rextester to reproduce it herer: http://rextester.com/QBRSS10238

**Attention!** 
I do not recommend you to use a `CROSS JOIN` here. Do you really need every user with every city? Even if they don't have a record in TBl3? You will have a lot of records with "`value = 0`" and the amount of records returned will increase massively if there are a few more users and cities.
Just imagine you have a table with 1500 users and 80 cities. Your CROSS JOIN will return 120.000 records. Even if just a very few have a match in table Tbl3.

If you just need users and cities, which have an entry in Tbl3. Start the select with Tbl3 and just join the tables user and cities like:

```
SELECT c.id as Cityid
      ,u.id as userId
      ,T3.value
  FROM TBl3 T3
 INNER JOIN usertbl u
    ON T3.userid = u.id
 INNER JOIN citytbl c
    ON T3.Cityid = c.id
```

Comment: thanks :) it works...i want to use a where clause to filter user and city...can you help me in it?

Comment: @SedigheRahimi happy to hear it works. to filter your results: try it by yourself first and use the stackoverflow search. its better to put some effort in it to solve it by yourself, as you will learn a lot, than just waiting for somebody else to solve it.